# Connect infinispan js client to a server requiring authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, infinispan

How can an infinispan js connect to an infinispan server requiring authentication ?
I did not find any reference to authentication in the infinispan js documentation.

Comment: how did you create the authentication in the server? what is your Infinispan version?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible yet, but it is scheduled soon: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/HRJS-36